# My Roses have disease gall?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, diseases, roses

I have noticed the discoloring of the stems of my roses. Do I have to remove the discolored stems? Aside from cleaning my cutting tools, is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Comment: Good question; if could include close illustrations of the stems & discolored portions of the stems, the leaves, an overall illustration, and how long it's been present, could be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Also, you can include illustrations that appear within the text of your questions by clicking on the scenery/mountain silhouette button, and then adding images according to the instructions which appear, and you can adjust text of your questions and answers, by clicking on the 'edit' button in the lower left corner of your question screen & answer screen. Thank you, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Can you edit your post to say where you are in the world, as well as adding a photo or two showing the problem please.